# Sklearn NotFittedError for CountVectorizer in pipeline

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf, countvectorizer

I am trying to learn how to work with text data through sklearn and am running into an issue that I cannot solve.

The tutorial I'm following is: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html

The input is a pandas df with two columns. One with text, one with a binary class.

Code:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

traindf, testdf = train_test_split(nlp_df, stratify=nlp_df['class'])

x_train = traindf['text']
x_test = traindf['text']
y_train = traindf['class']
y_test = testdf['class']

# CV
count_vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
x_train_modified = count_vect.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test_modified = count_vect.transform(x_test)


# TF-IDF
idf = TfidfTransformer()
fit = idf.fit(x_train_modified)
x_train_mod2 = fit.transform(x_train_modified)

# MNB

mnb = MultinomialNB()
x_train_data = mnb.fit(x_train_mod2, y_train)

text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
             ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
               ('clf', MultinomialNB()),
                ])

predicted = text_clf.predict(x_test_modified)
```

When I try to run the last line:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFittedError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-8815003b4713> in <module>()
----> 1 predicted = text_clf.predict(x_test_modified)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/metaestimators.py in <lambda>(*args, **kwargs)
    113 
    114         # lambda, but not partial, allows help() to work with update_wrapper
--> 115         out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    116         # update the docstring of the returned function
    117         update_wrapper(out, self.fn)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in predict(self, X)
    304         for name, transform in self.steps[:-1]:
    305             if transform is not None:
--> 306                 Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
    307         return self.steps[-1][-1].predict(Xt)
    308 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in transform(self, raw_documents)
    918             self._validate_vocabulary()
    919 
--> 920         self._check_vocabulary()
    921 
    922         # use the same matrix-building strategy as fit_transform

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in _check_vocabulary(self)
    301         """Check if vocabulary is empty or missing (not fit-ed)"""
    302         msg = "%(name)s - Vocabulary wasn't fitted."
--> 303         check_is_fitted(self, 'vocabulary_', msg=msg),
    304 
    305         if len(self.vocabulary_) == 0:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_is_fitted(estimator, attributes, msg, all_or_any)
    766 
    767     if not all_or_any([hasattr(estimator, attr) for attr in attributes]):
--> 768         raise NotFittedError(msg % {'name': type(estimator).__name__})
    769 
    770 

NotFittedError: CountVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted.
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this error? I am properly transforming the CV model on the test data. I even checked if the vocabulary list was empty and it isn't (count_vect.vocabulary_)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your question.

For starters, you don't actually *fit* the pipeline, hence the error. Looking more closely in the [linked tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#building-a-pipeline), you'll see that there is a step `text_clf.fit` (where `text_clf` is indeed the pipeline).

Second, you don't use the *notion* of the pipeline correctly, which is exactly to fit end-to-end the whole stuff; instead, you fit the individual components of it one by one... If you check again the tutorial, you'll see that the code for the *pipeline fit*:

```py
text_clf.fit(twenty_train.data, twenty_train.target)
```

uses the data in their initial form, *not* their intermediate transformations, as you do; the point of the tutorial is to demonstrate how the individual transformations can be wrapped-up in (and replaced by) a pipeline, *not* to use the pipeline on top of these transformations...

Third, you should avoid naming variables as `fit` - this is a reserved keyword; and similarly, we don't use  CV to abbreviate Count Vectorizer (in ML lingo, CV stands for cross validation).

That said, here is the correct way for using your pipeline:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

traindf, testdf = train_test_split(nlp_df, stratify=nlp_df['class'])

x_train = traindf['text']
x_test = traindf['text']
y_train = traindf['class']
y_test = testdf['class']

text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')),
                    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                    ('clf', MultinomialNB()),
                     ])

text_clf.fit(x_train, y_train) 

predicted = text_clf.predict(x_test)
```

As you can see, the purpose of the pipelines is to make things *simpler* (compared to using the components one by one sequentially), not to complicate them further...

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Definitely need to read into the Pipeline documentation first!